# Small touch target and can't drag MKPinAnnotationView up, but can drag every other direction?

Tags: macos, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I have a MKMapView with a draggable MKPinAnnotationView which is generally working well, but there are 2 significant issues:

1. Once I am dragging, if I reach the left, right or bottom of the map, it seamlessly scrolls the map as you would expect. However, when I drag upwards, about ~50px away from the top of the map it just stops and won't pan the map upwards.
2. The click target for the drag operation is tiny and pretty challenging to hit. Once I find the exact spot it works pretty well, but it's surprising it is so small. I've tried playing with the size of my custom pin image but it hasn't made a difference.

What could be causing these issues? Everything else about it is working great. Thank you!